# OpenCV not working with Cocoapods iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, cocoapods

I am trying to use OpenCV Framework from cocoapods

It is showing the error when I wrote pod install

> Unable to find a specification for `OpenCV`

Can anyone help me with the solution?

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'Driver App' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.3'
pod 'CLImageEditor'
pod 'OpenCV'
end

target 'Driver AppTests' do

end
```

Comment: paste your `podfile`

Comment: # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'Driver App' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.3'
pod 'CLImageEditor'
pod 'OpenCV'
end

target 'Driver AppTests' do

end

Comment: Please add in question with format

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'Driver App' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.3'
pod 'CLImageEditor', '~> 0.1'
pod 'OpenCV', '~> 3.0'
end

target 'Driver AppTests' do

end
```

Comment: [!] Unable to find a specification for `OpenCV (~> 3.0)`

Comment: try to use this link http://download.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-ios/3.0.0/opencv2.framework.zip

soundforge must be blocked on your network